# Hensen inequality in trigonometry: $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C \leq \frac{3}{2} \cdot \sqrt[2]{3} $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, triangles

Can anyone help me how to prove $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C \leq \frac{3}{2} \cdot \sqrt[2]{3} $

I have idea use Jensen but how to use it here?

Comment: If $A=B=C=90^\circ$ then $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=3>\dfrac 3 2 \sqrt{3}$.  If you intended some hypothesis on $A,B,C$, e.g. they are the three angles in a triangle, then that should be stated.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered, using Jensen's inequality, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/990423/195938