# Prove that $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C\leq \frac{3}{2}\sqrt3$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization

If $A,B,C$ are the angles of a triangle, prove that $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C\leq \frac{3}{2}\sqrt3$

---

I want to prove this inequality without Jensen's inequality, as Jensen is not in my syllabus.
Let $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=x$
$2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}+2\sin\frac{C}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}=x$
$4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}=x$
I do not know how to solve it further. I want to convert $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=x$ into a quadratic equation of some trigonometric function and then use the discriminant property. Please help.